# NetworkStream.DataAvailable is true even if there is no data on server side

Tags: c#, .net, networkstream

I have 2 simple applications - server and client. For now, server just waiting for a client to connect, prints networkstream.DataAvailable status, freezes for 5 sec and prints networkstream.DataAvailable status again.
Client does the same thing, except it  doesn't wait for connection but connects to server.
Server-side code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        int port = 8880;
        IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

        TcpListener serverListener = new TcpListener(localAddress, port);
        serverListener.Start();
        TcpClient incomingConnection = serverListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        IPEndPoint RemAddr = (IPEndPoint)incomingConnection.Client.RemoteEndPoint; ;
        Console.WriteLine("Connection: {0}:{1}", RemAddr.Address, RemAddr.Port);

        NetworkStream networkStream = incomingConnection.GetStream();

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(networkStream, Encoding.UTF8) { AutoFlush = true };            
        Console.WriteLine("networkstream.DataAvailable is {0}", networkStream.DataAvailable);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("networkstream.DataAvailable is {0}", networkStream.DataAvailable);
        ...
```

Client-side code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress remoteaddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

        int port = 8880;
        TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
        tcpclient.Connect(remoteaddr, port);
        NetworkStream networkstream = tcpclient.GetStream();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(networkstream, Encoding.UTF8);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(networkstream, Encoding.UTF8);

        Console.WriteLine("networkstream.DataAvailable is {0}", networkstream.DataAvailable);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("networkstream.DataAvailable is {0}", networkstream.DataAvailable);
        ...
```

So, here I have a problem. On server side I have the following output:

```
Connection: 127.0.0.1:55919
networkstream.DataAvailable is False
networkstream.DataAvailable is False
```

On server side output is:

```
networkstream.DataAvailable is False
networkstream.DataAvailable is True
```

So client shows that there is data in my networkStream. But there is no any data! And this is a problem, because in my application I use networkstream.DataAvailable to detect if there any data sent from server.
So, question is - what am I doing wrong? How to check availability of data properly?

Comment: Try to call the Read method when DataAvailable = true. It should return immediately, and will return the actual number of bytes read.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque did you mean sr.Read() or networkstream.Read()? When I'm trying to call sr.Read() it just freezes (like it waits for server to response). When I call networkstream.Read(), it reads 3 bytes - 239,187,191. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) says these bytes are byte order mask. But I don't understand why server keeps saying that therer is no data in stream. And I still don't know, how to deal with it. As I said, when I'm trying to call sr.Read() it just freezes. Should I use networkstream.read() instead?

Comment: From the server perspective, there is nothing to read, since the client didn't write anything. I think the StreamWriter writes the BOM when you create it, hence the 3 bytes. And sr.Read() tries to read a character, but there is nothing to read beyond the BOM, so it blocks.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque thanks! it's clear for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Levesque answered my question in comments section:

From the server perspective, there is nothing to read, since the client didn't write anything. I think the StreamWriter writes the BOM when you create it, hence the 3 bytes. And sr.Read() tries to read a character, but there is nothing to read beyond the BOM, so it blocks. –  Thomas Levesque 10 mins ago

Comment: Also note that any usage of DataAvailable or Available is 99% a bug. It is not necessary to use these values.